# Python OS.popen error

Tags: python, popen

I'm trying to get a few filenames by executing this command in os.popen :

```
ls /etc/tor/statistiekjes/ |egrep dns
```

But when I run my script I get :

```
<open file 'ls /etc/tor/statistiekjes/ |egrep dns', mode 'r' at 0xb7786860>
egrep: write error: Broken pipe
```

Code :

```
lscmd = "ls /etc/tor/statistiekjes/ |egrep "+FILE
print lscmd
inputList=os.popen(lscmd,'r')
```

File is an argument past to the script to grep on

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For this particular problem, you could use native Python calls:

```
import os
import re
for name in (name for name in  os.listdir('/etc/tor/statistiekjes/')
             if re.search(FILE,name)):
    print(repr(name))
```

However, you are probably looking for a more general solution to calling external programs. In that case, use `subprocess` instead of `os.popen`, since `os.popen` is deprecated:

```
import subprocess
import shlex
proc1 = subprocess.Popen(shlex.split('ls /etc/tor/statistiekjes/'),
                         stdout=subprocess.PIPE)
proc2 = subprocess.Popen(shlex.split('egrep {pat}'.format(pat=FILE)),
                         stdin=proc1.stdout,
                         stdout=subprocess.PIPE,stderr=subprocess.PIPE)

proc1.stdout.close() # Allow proc1 to receive a SIGPIPE if proc2 exits.
out,err=proc2.communicate()
print(out)
```

See ["Replacing shell pipeline"](http://docs.python.org/library/subprocess.html#replacing-shell-pipeline).

PS. `subprocess.Popen` has a `shell=True` parameter which could also be used. However, it is best to avoid using `shell=True` if possible. [It is a security risk](http://docs.python.org/library/subprocess.html#frequently-used-arguments).

Answer (score 2):

You can use subprocess.Popen, with shell=True flags:

```
from subprocess import Popen, PIPE
lscmd = "ls /etc/tor/statistiekjes/ |egrep "+FILE
inputList = Popen(lscmd, shell=True, stdout=PIPE).communicate()[0]
print inputList
```

Enjoy.